# ¿Es posible poder crear un datafile on una extension diferente a .DBF en una base de datos ORACLE?

Tags: oracle

que tal y gracias de antemano por leer esta pregunta.
Quisiera información sobre si yo puedo almacenar un datafile  una base de datos oracle con una extensión diferente a los .DBS. Y en caso si se pueda, en que casos o situaciones es posible esto?
saludos.

Comment: Según entiendo, poder se puede, `dbf` es la extensión estándar, pero puedes usar cualquier otra, eso lo decides a la hora de crear los datafile.

Comment: Y por ejemplo si tengo un datafile con extensión .ORA o cualquier otra, este datafile funcionará como uno con la extensión .DBF?

Comment: Mientras el nombre sea válido no debieras tener ningún inconveniente.

Answer (score 2):

Si es posible utilizar otras extensiones, el motor de base de datos no impone ninguna extensión en particular para los archivos de datos (*data files*).

Generalmente, dependen de la cultura del DBA y suelen ser `.dbf` u `.ora`. En general, yo prefiero la segunda, pero puedes utilizar la de tu preferencia.

Lo que es recomendable es que utilices una extensión que no entre en conflicto con otras que puedan ser *reconocidas* por tu sistema, así como que configures procesos que puedan perjudicar el desempeño de la base de datos, por ejemplo, antivirus, de manera que no estén escaneando estos archivos.